# $X\succeq0$ with rank $r\leq n\Rightarrow X=V^TV$ where $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I saw this statement, and was wondering about the proof:

$X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite with rank $r\Longrightarrow X=V^TV$ where $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$.

Comment: There's a very quick proof if we can use [the spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case)

Comment: Do you mean that $X=\sum_i \lambda_i v_i v_i^T$ where the $v_i$ are orthonormal and in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: yes exactly, and $v_i$ are the eigenvectors of $X$

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how that helps us construct $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $V$ to be the matrix whose $i$th row is $\sqrt{\lambda_i} v_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $X$.

Comment: But $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$, so it can't be a column of $V$

Comment: It could be a row. Although are we guaranteed that there are exactly $r=\operatorname{rank}(X)$ eigenvectors?

Comment: If $V \in \Bbb R^{r \times n}$, then every column of $V$ has $n$ entries.  So why can't $v_i$ be a column of $V$?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but $V\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times n}$ is a matrix with $r$ rows and $n$ columns. If there are $r$ rows, then each column has length $r$.

Comment: @Dan you're right not sure where my head was at

Comment: @Dan that being said taking $v_i$ to be the rows of $V$ works

Comment: For a symmetric matrix (or any diagonalizable matrix), we are guaranteed that the number of non-zero eigenvalues coincides with the rank

Comment: Ah okay that solves it for me. I did not know of such a guarantee

Comment: @Dan note that the kernel of an operator is the eigenspace associated with zero, so that the dimension of the kernel is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue zero.